# Receive Addressbook data in iOS7 xCode (iOS 6 is working)

Tags: objective-c, addressbook, ios7

Hello i want to receive the addressbook data, in ios6 this code is working perfect! But in ios7 it isnt showing the NSLOG :( Can somebody help me?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

        NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
            NSString *phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
            NSLog(@"phone:%@", phoneNumber);
        }

    }




    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Comment: You need to check if the app has permission to access the address book. This is true as of iOS 6.0.

Comment: Please be aware, that iOS 7 is still under NDA. Therefore it should not be discussed outside of the apple developer forums.